# Behaviour of disabling "Allow non-administrators to receive notifications" GPO

Tags: windows, group-policy, non-admin, wsus

As the title suggests, I'm trying to figure out the specific behaviour of the following GPO when disabled:

> Administrative Templates > Windows
>   Components > Allow non-administrators
>   to receive update notifications

We've just started using WSUS, and have added a few machines for testing. At the moment, this is set to Enabled. The problem with this setting is it seems to allow users to opt out of certain updates if they deselect the checkbox after hitting custom install.

My main concern with disabling this setting is this: **Does it stop non-admins from getting the installs deployed to them?**

My guess would be that it will just install them silently at the set scheduled time, suppressing any prompts and ensuring they don't get the opportunity to cancel them (this is what I want).

My worry is that non-admin users will never get updates pushed to them unless an admin goes and logs on to their machine (not what I want, and seems like a silly situation to be in).

Thanks in advance,
Jaymz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using WSUS you should follow these Microsoft guidelines [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708574%28WS.10%29.aspx) when it comes to configuring Group Policy.

With regards to that specific policy, enabling will allow logged on non-admins to receive notifications about new updates being available. if it is disabled or set to not configured, then any update notification prompts are suppressed.

Enabling this policy will not stop the installs to non-admins however it will stop any notifications being made available to non-admins.